# manipulating image size onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this div with 4 images.  with set dimension of image is 100px.
what i  want is when these images are clicked i want them to increase to 300px.

here is my html

```
<button id="first1" class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Supports FAQ Single Operator " ng-click="select_chat_type('1')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='1'}">Chat Box FAQ<br>
<img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listchat11.png?v=1623415967">
                              </button>
<button id="first2"  class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Single Operator,When clicked whatsapp app will be launched" ng-click="select_chat_type('2')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='2'}">Direct Whatsapp <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/directcchat.png?v=1623416104">
</button>
<button id="first3"  class="secondary tip ng-binding button-selected" data-hover="Multi Operator Supported Here,List Sales, Support, Technical etc department. Timers will work here for Online &amp; Offline" ng-click="select_chat_type('3')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='3'}">List Departments + On:Off<br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listdepppttt.png?v=1623416352"></button>
<button id="first4"  class="secondary tip" data-hover="Single Operator,Small Chat box,Plz adjust width" ng-click="select_chat_type('4')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='4'}">Baby Chat <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/babychat11.png?v=1623416725"></button>
```

i am using this code increasesize class

```
.increasesize {
    width: 100px;
}

.increasesize.clicked {
    width: 300px;
}
```

sometimes it works sometimes it does not work.

what i want is when any button is clicked all other buttons should  go back to 100px and the clicked button should be 300px

i want to use jquery for doing this.
we have added id for each buttons. we can achieve this by something like this

```
$('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').click(function(event) 
{ 
var idpiiu = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+idpiiu).width( 300 );

 //   $("#first1").width( 300 );
    $("#first2,first3,first4").width( 100 );

});
```

but then i have to repeat same for all other ids. i am sure there must be some better way
i think this.id  should solve this issue.

Comment: This is missing `#` `$(idpiiu)` should be `$("#"+idpiiu)`. Also `$("#first2,first3,first4").width( 100 );` should be `$("#first2,#first3,#first4").width( 100 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing multiple `#` in your code.

You should also switch the other, so you reduce the width of all of them and then set the width of the element clicked.

You can also do `$('div[id^=first]')` instead of `$('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4')`. This will select all div elements where the id starts with `first`

```
$('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').click(function(event) {
  $('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').width(100);
  $(this).width(300);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').click(function(event) {
  $('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').width(100);
  $(this).width(300);
});
```

```css
.increasesize {
  width: 100px;
}

.increasesize.clicked {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="first1" class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Supports FAQ Single Operator " ng-click="select_chat_type('1')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='1'}">Chat Box FAQ<br>
<img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listchat11.png?v=1623415967">
                              </button>
<button id="first2" class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Single Operator,When clicked whatsapp app will be launched" ng-click="select_chat_type('2')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='2'}">Direct Whatsapp <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/directcchat.png?v=1623416104">
</button>
<button id="first3" class="secondary tip ng-binding button-selected" data-hover="Multi Operator Supported Here,List Sales, Support, Technical etc department. Timers will work here for Online &amp; Offline" ng-click="select_chat_type('3')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='3'}">List Departments + On:Off<br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listdepppttt.png?v=1623416352"></button>
<button id="first4" class="secondary tip" data-hover="Single Operator,Small Chat box,Plz adjust width" ng-click="select_chat_type('4')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='4'}">Baby Chat <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/babychat11.png?v=1623416725"></button>
```

Comment: this idea is awesome. i could not think this . very very sorry ..  $('#first1,#first2,#first3,#first4').width(100);

Comment: @sonutup No need to be sorry, we all have to learn. Just happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 <div class="nav">
      <button id="first1" class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Supports FAQ Single Operator " ng-click="select_chat_type('1')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='1'}">Chat Box FAQ<br> <img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listchat11.png?v=1623415967"></button>
      <button id="first2"  class="secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Single Operator,When clicked whatsapp app will be launched" ng-click="select_chat_type('2')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='2'}">Direct Whatsapp <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/directcchat.png?v=1623416104"></button>
      <button id="first3"  class="secondary tip ng-binding button-selected" data-hover="Multi Operator Supported Here,List Sales, Support, Technical etc department. Timers will work here for Online &amp; Offline" ng-click="select_chat_type('3')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='3'}">List Departments + On:Off<br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listdepppttt.png?v=1623416352"></button>
      <button id="first4"  class="secondary tip" data-hover="Single Operator,Small Chat box,Plz adjust width" ng-click="select_chat_type('4')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='4'}">Baby Chat <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/babychat11.png?v=1623416725"></button> 
</div>
```

```
li.active {
  color: red;
}
          
button .increasesize {
  width: 100px;
}
          
button.clicked .increasesize {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```
var selector = '.nav button';        
 $(selector).on('click', function(){
     $(selector).removeClass('clicked');
     $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

If code doesn't run here open this https://codepen.io/sam-123/pen/qBmgjRm

Comment: Please take your time and format the answer so it's easy to read before posting. If not it could result in people downvoting your answer because it's not easy to read

Comment: I am facing difficulties in formatting the code that is why I am also adding the codepen link, I'll try to edit it, I have already downgraded once, But Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: Consider not using codepen, but when your create or edit your answer use the snippet tool. looks like `<>`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks a lot for your advice  I have tried Editing it and looks like    its much cleaner now

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of elements, I recommend using class. it makes the code simpler.

```
$('.image-click').click(function(event) {
  $('.image-click').width(100)
  $(this).width(300)
});
```

```js
$('.image-click').click(function(event) {
  $('.image-click').width(100)
  $(this).width(300)
});
```

```css
.increasesize {
    width: 100px;
}

.increasesize.clicked {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="first1" class="image-click secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Supports FAQ Single Operator " ng-click="select_chat_type('1')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='1'}">Chat Box FAQ<br>
<img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listchat11.png?v=1623415967">
                              </button>
<button id="first2"  class="image-click secondary tip ng-binding" data-hover="Single Operator,When clicked whatsapp app will be launched" ng-click="select_chat_type('2')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='2'}">Direct Whatsapp <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/directcchat.png?v=1623416104">
</button>
<button id="first3"  class="image-click secondary tip ng-binding button-selected" data-hover="Multi Operator Supported Here,List Sales, Support, Technical etc department. Timers will work here for Online &amp; Offline" ng-click="select_chat_type('3')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='3'}">List Departments + On:Off<br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/listdepppttt.png?v=1623416352"></button>
<button id="first4"  class="image-click secondary tip" data-hover="Single Operator,Small Chat box,Plz adjust width" ng-click="select_chat_type('4')" ng-class="{'button-selected': data.chat_type=='4'}">Baby Chat <br><img class="increasesize" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/babychat11.png?v=1623416725"></button>
```

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pw1d6k98/